# MySQL if join table.col exists case as part of the query itself?

Tags: mysql, database, relational-database

I have a weird situation here that I try to resolve through SQL so I don't have to modify much in the application :).
Is there ANY way that I can tell if a column exists in a quere within the query?
(Table2 is not always joined in the query)

```
SELECT * FROM
Table1 as T1
join Table2 as T2 on t1.id = t2.fk
WHERE
T1.something > 10 OR (IF(table and column exists in the query T2.col, 1, 0);
```

my alternative is to always join Table2 (painful in this case).
Any SQL guru/genius can help?

Comment: To tell if a column exists? Have you tried querying the `information_schema`?

Comment: Where does your query come from? Is it generated? maybe by a PHP script?

Comment: The problem was a join was not always made. So I needed to figure out in an sql way if it had been made. Dumb me, I didn't see it the other way around, "joining" at that given point with a nested select so I could grab the column of interest from a table. The solution presented below solved my problem quite easily :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with an easy work around. So, for the sake of referencing...

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 as T1
WHERE T1.something > 10 OR ((SELECT ....) = 1)
```